# How to reduce ProcessPoolExecutor's cpu usage with asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I use `ProcessPoolExecutor` like below

```
def main(argv):
    set_argv(argv)
    # running code. Loop button click, enter text, submit.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executer = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=9)
    argvs = ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    for argv in argvs:
        executer.submit(main,argv)
```

But this code use CPU 100% and each process takes twice as long to complete only one process.

So I want to use `asyncio` to reduce CPU usage. but the code below generates an error.

```
async def async_set():
    coroutines = []
    argvs = ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    fts = [loop.run_in_executor(main(m)) for m in argvs]
    for f in asyncio.as_completed(fts, loop=loop):
        await f

async def main(argv):
    set_argv(argv)
    # running code. Loop button click, enter text, submit.

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_set())
    loop.close()
```

And the error is:

```
 fts = [loop.run_in_executor(main(m)) for m in argvs]
TypeError: run_in_executor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

After change `fts` like below

`fts = [loop.run_in_executor(None, main, m) for m in argvs]`

There was an error, **but Just 1 process running normally**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/Version/test.py", line 593, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(async_set())
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/Version/test.py", line 60, in async_set
    await f
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 533, in _wait_for_one
    return f.result()  # May raise f.exception().
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/Version/test.py", line 67, in main
    set_login(ID, PW)
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/Version/test.py", line 188, in set_login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li[1]/a').click()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

Comment: The [call signature for that method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) is `(executor, func, *args)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how well this mimics your process but this runs:

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

def main(argv):
    t = random.choice([.02,.1,.5,.3,1.0,2.0,3.0,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.])
    time.sleep(t)
    return (t, argv * 2)

async def async_set():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
##    coroutines = []
    argvs = ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        stuff = [loop.run_in_executor(pool,main,arg) for arg in argvs]
        for fut in asyncio.as_completed(stuff):
            print(await fut)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_set())
    loop.close()

>>>
(0.5, 'EE')
(0.5, 'DD')
(0.5, 'FF')
(7.0, 'HH')
(8.0, 'II')
(0.1, 'LL')
(9.0, 'GG')
(9.0, 'JJ')
(7.0, 'KK')
>>>
```

Comment: This works. But the usage of CPU is still 100%.... There's no substantial improvement..